# how to reference two different tags? working with tooltips!

Tags: jquery, html, css, tags, reference

I want to be able to create a tooltip, but having referencing from two different places

```
    this.tooltip = function(){  

        xOffset = 10;
    yOffset = 20;       


    $("div.tooltip").hover(function(e){                                           
        this.t = $("a.tooltip").title;
        $("a.tooltip").title = "";                                    
        $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</p>");
        $("#tooltip")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");        
    },
    function(){
        this.title = this.t;        
        $("#tooltip").remove();
    }); 
    $("div.tooltip").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#tooltip")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });         
};



// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
    tooltip();
});
```

This is where I wanted to be able to work with. I have a text "Roll over for tooltip", then a box saying "Web Standards Magazine" will pop up.

```
<div class="tooltip">Roll over for tooltip</div>
<span class="tooltip" title="Web Standards Magazine"></a>
```

I know there's ways where you can just have it one area like

```
<span class="tooltip" title="Web Standards Magazine">Roll over for tooltip</a>
```

The reason why i'm not doing this is because I'm working on a small part of a larger file and I don't want to mess anything up.

I'm getting undefined variable. Need help please, Thanks!

Comment: The question tags are really confusing.

Comment: What exactly are the `<div>`s doing? They're empty.

Comment: Why do you want to have them in a div when you could just as well put them into the title tag of the img elements directly?

Comment: @pimvdb its empty because as I was reading other tooltip tutorials, they use the attribute title. This way I'm just showing an example to get my question across

@Gordon its because I'm modifying a little part of a large file script, and I don't want to mess with moving a lot of things, so I'm just trying to reference them togethrr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're doing some event like a `hover()`, you can concatenate the `class` of the element that received the event into the [`id-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) in order to select the corresponding `<div>`.

```
$('img[class^="tooltip"]').hover(function() {
    $('#' + this.className).fadeIn();  // fadeIn, or do whatever with the div
},
  function() {
    $('#' + this.className).fadeOut();  // fadeOut, or do whatever with the div
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was wondering if you could help me out a little more? I thought I was able to do this on my own :(

Answer (score 1):

```
var tooltip = $('#' + this.className).attr('title');
```

Will give you the `tooltip's title` that is linked to the div, given that `$(this)` is the img